# Caesar decipher

Tags: python, beginner, caesar-cipher

I have recently started learning Python and one of the assignments I have been working on is a Caesar decipher.

Can you tell me how I can make my code better?

```
def caesar(code, shift):
  ''' (str, int) -> str
  Shift every letter in the code by the integer 'shift'.
  >>> caesar('ABC', 2)
  CDE
  >>> caesar('a b c', 4)
  e f g
  '''
  decipher = ''
  for char in code:
    if 65<=ord(char)<=90:
        decipher = decipher + chr((ord(char) - 65 + shift)%26+65)
    if 97<=ord(char)<=122:
        decipher = decipher + chr((ord(char) - 97 + shift)%26+97)
    else:
      decipher += char
  return decipher
```

Comment: this is broken, `caesar('ABC', 2)` returns `CADBEC` http://ideone.com/67tG6Z

Comment: Oh, thank you! It should be elif instead of if.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 4 → 3. @miracle173, the bug you spotted [should be posted as an answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1479/9357) so that it can earn the points it deserves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), **standard indentation** for Python is 4 spaces.  In a language where whitespace is syntactically significant, this is an important convention to follow.

The **naming** of the parameter `code` and the variable `decipher` are slightly off, especially with the latter being a verb.  I suggest `ciphertext` and `plaintext`.

Inside the loop, the **three branches are mutually exclusive**.  I suggest writing them as `if … elif … else …`.  You used the `+=` concatenation operator in the `else` branch; I wonder why you didn't do likewise in the other two cases.

You have a lot of **magic numbers** in the code.  The first branch could be more clearly written as

```
if 'A' <= char <= 'Z':
    plaintext += chr((ord(char) - ord('A') + shift) % 26 + ord('A'))
```

Iterating using `for char in code` is good.  Many Python beginners try to do something complicated, like `i = 0; while i < len(code): char = code[i]`.  Even better would have been to use a **list comprehension**, so as to avoid creating another immutable string every time you append a character to the result.  Here is one possible way to write it:

```
def caesar(ciphertext, shift):
   def decipher(alpha_start, alpha_size, c, shift):
        if alpha_start <= ord(c) < alpha_start + alpha_size:
            return chr((ord(c) - alpha_start + shift) % alpha_size + alpha_start)
   return ''.join([decipher(ord('A'), 26, c, shift) or
                   decipher(ord('a'), 26, c, shift) or c
                   for c in ciphertext])
```

Comment: if the three branches are mutual exlusive they cannot be implemented in the way done in the OP